# Sprite Not Drawn in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to Pygame and I don't understand why the sprite isn't being drawn on the screen. Can someone show me how or what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((603, 480))

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
x = "1"
y = "1"

loop = True
while loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False

def Player(Sprite):
    image=("Player.png")
    def __init__(self, image,  groups):
        pygame.update

screen.fill (WHITE)
Player(x, y)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: There are many problems with your code. I'd suggest looking up a beginner tutorial on Python first and then search for a pygame tutorial on Youtube or the pygame's offical website.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Why the x and y is string???
You are saying a position like a word. The type of pos must be int or float.

```
x = 1
y = 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).